# Speeding up CsQuery selectors by using html substring

Tags: html, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-parser, csquery

I want to parse some complex/heavy HTML pages. I recently read about CsQuery and checked the performance comparation of [CsQuery Vs Html Agility Pack and Fizzler](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/csquery-performance-vs-fizzler.html) . According to these tests, CsQuery turns to be slower when creating the DOM due to its index creation.

Let's say I want to select certain element (without an id) of a heavy html page, and I know the ID of an ancestor of it, which I will use as a context element. If I load this heavy html into DOM, it will be slow, therefore my selection will be slow. However, if I can SOMEHOW FAST pre-process the html and get the sub-string containing the context element (which ID I know) and load that into DOM, it will be faster. In that case I would have gotten rid of lots of unneeded HTML for which indexers will not be created. Therefore, my selection will be faster.

I am using CsQuery because I want something JQuery-like.

My question is:

Given an HTML document string: Is there a FAST WAY (eg:  linear) to get the HTML sub-string of an HTML element given its id?

Comment: Were you able to get my suggestion working?

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me say that I think you've made the correct choice with CsQuery, I switched from HAP to it a while ago and I couldn't be happier with the switch.
The newest pre-release of CsQuery lets you turn off indexing completely, or only do partial indexing of your code.

From the issue tracker.

> In the current prerelease code there's an alternate indexing strategy you can use which speeds up DOM construction quite a bit, at the expense of complex queries. (Actually there's two new strategies, you can turn the index off altogether if you really want to :) This may be better for the kind of scenarios you're dealing with.

If you're willing to download the code from its [git-hub](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) repository and compile it, working with the pre-release you'll be able to do just that.

The [DomIndexProviders](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/source/CsQuery/Engine/DomIndexProviders.cs) class contains 3 options, `RangedDomIndexProvider` which indexes a lot of selectors and is very clever `SimpleDomIndexProvider` which allows basic indexing and `NoDomIndexProvider` which does not do indexing at all. [`SimpleDomIndexProvider`](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/source/CsQuery/Engine/DomIndexSimple.cs) is very straightforward and might work in your case, you might also consider [no indexing](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/source/CsQuery/Engine/DomIndexNone.cs).

Comment: The new version with this feature is also available on NuGet now if you "include preleeases" http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/1.3.5-beta3